# How to create TextRenderer info manually

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I need to create TextRendererInfo manually for adding space character but when I try to add it that way:

```
final TextRenderInfo spaceInfo = new TextRenderInfo(new PdfString(" "), newStringInfo.getGraphicsState(), newStringInfo.getTextMatrix(), new Stack<>());
System.out.println(spaceInfo.getText()); // I will get the following character �
```

Why it can't return a correct text?
How can I create the TextRendererInfo correctly and getText() must return to me the space character?

Comment: One idea is to get the `TextRenderInfo` for  `new PdfString("Xj Xj")` and the `TextRenderInfo` for  `new PdfString("XjXj")` and calculate the difference.

Comment: The `TextRenderInfo` method `getText()` assumes its `PdfString` to be encoded using the encoding of the font in its `CanvasGraphicsState`. You on the other hand create the `PdfString` without taking that encoding into account. Thus, what `getText()` returns for your created info object is quite arbitrary. Actually the font in that graphics state may not have an encoding for the space character at all.  Thus, I'd propose you clone that graphics state and replace the font therein by one with a space. And then encode the `PdfString` accordingly.